# Read XML from REST service with authentication

Tags: java, xml, rest, authentication

I tried to read xml from a REST service by

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()
    {
      @Override
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
      {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
      }
    });

Document doc = builder.parse(restString);
```

where `builder` is a `DocumentBuilder`.

Unfortunately, this does *not* seem to authorize the request: In Wireshark, I see no credentials attached to the GET request. The same request in curl works (and has credentials in the http request).

What is my mistake? Or should I contact REST services in an entirely different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does the trick if one uses `com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.19`:

```
  public static String getHttpResult(String url, String user, String password)
      throws IOException
  {

    Client client = Client.create();
    try
    {
      client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(user, password));

      try
      {
        WebResource wrget = client.resource(url);
        return wrget.get(String.class);
      }
      catch (UniformInterfaceException e)
      {
        throw new IOException("Fehler beim Zugriff auf " + url + " mit User "
            + user, e);

      }
    }
    finally
    {
      if (client != null)
        client.destroy();
    }
  }
```

This gives you the XML as a String. If you convert the String to an `InputSource`

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(httpResult));
doc = builder.parse(is);
```

You get what you want.